# module is not redirecting

Tags: module, magento-1

I created a module which I can see in the menu where I wanted to show it unfortunately it is not redirecting to the page, this module suppose to show the Grid 
I also enabled and write down the module in app/etc/modules and it is enabled no worry about that I am seeing the module in my menu
the page it should go is:

```
http://website.com/index.php/report/adminhtml_report/
```

but it is a **not found page**
here is the structure:

[image]

Report.php

```
class Report_ReserveMenu_Block_Adminhtml_Report extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_report';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'report';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('report')->__($navigation);

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );  
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

here is config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Report_ReserveMenu>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Report_ReserveMenu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Report_ReserveMenu>
                <class>Report_ReserveMenu_Helper</class>
            </Report_ReserveMenu>
        </helpers>  
        <blocks>
            <Report_ReserveMenu>
                <class>Report_ReserveMenu_Block</class>
            </Report_ReserveMenu>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
  <menu>
      <catalog>
          <children>
                <inventory>
        <children>
          <module name="Report_ReserveMenu">
            <title>03 Product Reserves</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <action>report/adminhtml_report</action>
          </module>
        </children>
        </inventory>
        </children>
      </catalog>
    </menu>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Report_ReserveMenu>
                    <file>report_menu.xml</file>
                </Report_ReserveMenu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
 </adminhtml>
</config>
```

also I have the update layout in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\report_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <report_adminhtml_report_index>    
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="report/adminhtml_report" name="report" as="events.codes.edit.report"/>
        </reference>
</report_adminhtml_report_index>
</layout>
```

the controller:

```
class Report_ReserveMenu_Adminhtml_ReportController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{   
protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/report/report');
    }

public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('report/adminhtml_report');// <---- then this
    $this->renderLayout();

}
public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('report/adminhtml_report_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }   
}
```

and also the grid which doesn't seem to be wrong. please tell me what is wrong with this module, if you need to see other files just let me know and I will update the question, I don't want somebody to create me a nice module and say ok use this I wanna know my problem because everytime I have the problem creating my own module and I have to copy paste some other module like a goooooof

Comment: `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action` should be `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`

Comment: I also changed it to Action no result

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your admin router in `config.xml`

```
<config>

...

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <report_reservemenu before="Mage_Adminhtml">Report_ReserveMenu_Adminhtml</report_reservemenu>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
 </admin>

 ...

 </config>
```

EDIT:

Also change in `config.xml`:

In the router, change `before` to `after`:

```
 after="Mage_Adminhtml"
```

And change:

```
 <title>03 Product Reserves</title>
 <sort_order>100</sort_order>
 <action>adminhtml/report</action>
```

The url in the admin menu will be: /admin/report/index

You can verify that your admin router is working by going to `controllers/Adminhtml/ReportController.php` and editing your `indexAction` like this:

```
public indexAction() {

     echo 'THIS WORKS';
     exit();

}
```

When you click on the menu you'll see a blank page with only "THIS WORKS" on it.

From there you can start troubleshooting your layouts.

Comment: I did it, it didn't work. also I have modules which are functioning but they don't have routers

Comment: I've never made an adminhtml extension with a router that didn't have it defined.  After adding the router did you flush your cache?

Comment: my cache is disabled

Comment: See edited answer above.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't show me `this works`, only the not found page I knew it doesn't go to my controller because I logged there before n it didn't work i dont know why though

Comment: I copied all of your code down and installed it on my local dev environment, made the modifications in my edit and it worked. Erase var/cache/* and try again.  Make sure you have everything exactly as I put it because this works for me locally.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to define admin url in magento. Each method required a different menu `<action>` url. See example below

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <menu1 translate="title" module="customlist">
            <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="SampleModule1">
                    <title>Menu item 1</title>
                    <action>{{adminhtml/customlist}}/index</action>
                </menuitem1>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_CustomList before="Mage_Adminhtml">Foo_Bar_Adminhtml</Company_CustomList>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Or

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <menu1 translate="title" module="customlist">
            <title>ActiveCodeline SampleModule1</title>
            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
            <children>
                <menuitem1 module="SampleModule1">
                    <title>Menu item 1</title>
                    <action>{{customlist}}/index</action>
                </menuitem1>


<admin>
    <routers>
        <samplemodule1>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>ActiveCodeline_SampleModule1</module>
                <frontname>customlist</frontname>
            </args>
        </samplemodule1>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: with doing this I just get some weird url but with mine the url seems correct with yours i have this http://website.com/index.php/%7B%7Breport%7D%7D/index/

Comment: Please update your question with your current config.xml

Comment: Without defining adminhtml in the `<action>` then it won't be an `/admin/` url.